# update existing ppt with excel file using vba

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have written the code and it is updating data in chartdata of ppt but entire range from external excel file is not being displayed when chart is produced.
So from code is pulling data from excel and pasting in chartdata of ppt but when chart is produced is shows only range a1:b4 whereas actual range is a1 : c4

```
Sub openppt()

Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim cht As PowerPoint.Chart
Dim chtData As PowerPoint.ChartData
Dim startcell As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PowerPointApp.Visible = True

DestinationPPT = "C:\Users\alex.samuel\Desktop\assignment\VBA Training.pptx"
PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open (DestinationPPT)

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations("VBA Training.pptx")

'Assume we have only one slide, at slide 1:
Set sld = myPresentation.Slides(1)

'Assume the Chart is the second shape, modify if needed
Set shp = sld.Shapes("Chart 29")
'Handle the chart
Set cht = shp.Chart
'Handle the CharttData
Set chtData = cht.ChartData
'Set Object
Set ws = Sheet1
Set startcell = Range("a1")

'Find last row and column in data
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = ws.Cells(startcell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'select dynamic range of data
ws.Range(startcell, ws.Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Select

'copy dynamic range
ws.Range(startcell, ws.Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Copy

'Open & minimize the ChartData, you don't need to see it, but it must be OPEN to edit it
chtData.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.setdatasource Source:=ws.Range("a1:c4")`enter code here`

End Sub
```

Comment: This code is working so, which one is your question? Did you check the size of your copied item? Just replicating your code and proccess I get the full range on PPT.

Comment: Thank you David, it is working now